# How to create and store value of the progress bars in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

First,I have a textarea for tasks and an add button. When the button is clicked it will be stored in the database.All I want to do is to output the task with a progress bar and buttons for increment and decrement.

Does anyone know about bootstrap progress bar?

- The progress bar must be incremented and decremented.
- and the last value must be the latest value of it when a user came back to that progress bar.

I think jquery and javascript is the best solution for this. But I do not know how :( Can someone please help.

heres the code for the output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Customize Bootstrap progressbar
    </title>
    <link href="bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body style="margin-top: 100px">
    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Customize Bootstrap progressbar
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 50px">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0 %" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="progress.increment(10)">
                        Increment
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="progress.decrement(10)">
                        Decrement
                    </button>
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default"onclick="progress.reset()">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default"onclick="progress.complete()">
                        Complete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var progress = (function ($) {
        var progress = $('.progress'),
            progress_bar = $('.progress-bar'),
            total_width = progress.width();
        function calculatePercentage(increment_by,is_increment) {
            var progress_percentage;
            if (is_increment == true) {
                progress_percentage = Math.round((progress_bar.width() / total_width) * 100 + increment_by) ;
                progress_percentage = (progress_percentage > 100) ? 100 : progress_percentage;
            } else {
                progress_percentage = Math.round((progress_bar.width() / total_width) * 100 - increment_by) ;
                progress_percentage = (progress_percentage < 0) ? 0 : progress_percentage;
            }
            return progress_percentage;
        }
        return{
            increment: function (increment_by) {
                var progress_percentage = calculatePercentage(increment_by, true);
                progress_bar.css('width',progress_percentage + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress_percentage + ' %');
            },
            decrement: function (decrement_by) {
                var progress_percentage = calculatePercentage(decrement_by, false);
                progress_bar.css('width',progress_percentage+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress_percentage + ' %');
            },
            reset: function () {
                progress_bar.css('width',0 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0 + ' %');
            },
            complete: function () {
                progress_bar.css('width',100 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 100 + ' %');
            }
        };
    })( jQuery);
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XlFH.png)

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Are looking for progress bar or slider?  You can store the state in a DB or local storage if you want to retain the state.

Comment: The design of the output. Progress bar and the buttons for increment and decrement.But w/o function.

Comment: @poushy progress bar is what im looking for

Comment: @akamariaclaraaa Please check this codepen... Is this what you are looking for http://codepen.io/jbeurel/pen/zuDAl

Comment: @poushy  i did saw that earlier but i only want an increment button that will add 10 to the current value or a decrement button that will subtract to the current value. And I also want the value to be the current value when i refresh the page.

Comment: @poushy I've added a code for the output on my question. But when i refresh it. The value returns to 0. :(

Comment: You need to store the state in DB or in local storage.  When the page refreshes, get those value, and you should use that data to set the progress bar values.

Comment: @poushy how can i store it? Sorry Im only new in this

Comment: Please check these examples for local storage implementation http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @poushy thank you :) I'll get back on you if i get it right :) .... or not.

Comment: @poushy how will i get the result through progress bar?

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @poushy nope not yet :(

Comment: You need to read the progress bar status and save it in local storage

Comment: but i do not know how to :( anyways thanks for the help

Comment: Are you stuck on the part about reading progress bar status or in local storage?

Comment: Both. :( hm what's happening is when i click the increment button all of the progress bar will increment. so i want to know about how can i do this per id of each entered tasks. look at the picture above.

Comment: @akamariaclaraaa - I have added an answer to your queries.  Please check it out.  Hope it helps you go ahead with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the localStorage as shown below.  Also I have converted the code to a jQuery plugin, which will be initialized per widget.  All your progressBars are incremented at once as you are using something like `progress_bar = $('.progress-bar')` which means you are picking up all the progress_bars on the page, not targetting a single progress bar.  I have create an attachEvent inside the plugin code, so you do not need to initialize the events from the dom.  In general its a good practice to attach events from the script.

I would suggest adding a function createHTML for your HTML creation and call that code in init to create your HTML. You can use the same localStorage to track how many progress bars you have on page, when you refresh the page, and need to recreate the progress bars.

Try using templates for the html, as repeated html is not ideal.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Customize Bootstrap progressbar
        </title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>


    </head>

     <body style="margin-top: 100px">
        <div class=" col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">
                         Customize Bootstrap progressbar
                     </h3>
                 </div>
                 <div id="progress-bar-1" class="progress-bar-widget">
                      <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 50px">
                          <div class="progress">
                              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0 %" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-footer">
                           <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default increment">
                                       Increment
                                 </button>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrement" >
                                        Decrement
                                  </button>
                                  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default reset">
                                       Reset
                                   </button>
                                   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default complete">
                                         Complete
                                    </button>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        <div id="progress-bar-2" class="progress-bar-widget">
                             <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 50px" class="progress-bar-widget">
                              <div class="progress">
                                   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0 %" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default increment" >
                                           Increment
                                     </button>
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default decrement" ">
                                           Decrement
                                     </button>
                                     <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default reset">
                                            Reset
                                      </button>
                                      <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default complete">
                                             Complete
                                      </button>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
        </body>
<script>
(function ($) {
 $.fn.progressBar = function( ) {
        var widget = $(this),
            progress = $(this).find('.progress'),
            progress_bar = $(this).find('.progress-bar'),
            total_width = progress.width();

        function init() {
            var curr_progress = getLocalStorage();
            if(curr_progress) {
                progress_bar.css('width',curr_progress + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', curr_progress + ' %');
            }
            attachEvents();
        }

        function attachEvents() {
            widget.find('.increment').on("click", function(){increment(10);});
            widget.find('.decrement').on("click", function(){decrement(10);});
            widget.find('.reset').on("click", reset);
            widget.find('.complete').on("click", complete);
        }
        function calculatePercentage(increment_by,is_increment) {
            var progress_percentage;
            if (is_increment == true) {
                progress_percentage = Math.round((progress_bar.width() / total_width) * 100 + increment_by) ;
                progress_percentage = (progress_percentage > 100) ? 100 : progress_percentage;
            } else {
                progress_percentage = Math.round((progress_bar.width() / total_width) * 100 - increment_by) ;
                progress_percentage = (progress_percentage < 0) ? 0 : progress_percentage;
            }
            return progress_percentage;
        }
        function getLocalStorage() {
            return localStorage.getItem(widget.attr('id'));
        }
        function setLocalStorage(val) {
            localStorage.setItem(widget.attr('id'), val);
        }

        function increment(increment_by) {
            var progress_percentage = calculatePercentage(increment_by, true);
            setLocalStorage(progress_percentage);
            progress_bar.css('width',progress_percentage + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress_percentage + ' %');
        };
        function decrement (decrement_by) {
            var progress_percentage = calculatePercentage(decrement_by, false);
            setLocalStorage(progress_percentage);
            progress_bar.css('width',progress_percentage+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress_percentage + ' %');
        };
        function reset () {
            setLocalStorage(0);
            progress_bar.css('width',0 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0 + ' %');
        };
        function complete () {
            setLocalStorage(100);
            progress_bar.css('width',100 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 100 + ' %');
        }

        init();
    }

    $('.progress-bar-widget').each(function(index, elem){
        $(elem).progressBar();
    });

})( jQuery);
</script>
```

Hope it helped! :) All the best!

Comment: :) All the best! @akamariaclaraaa

Comment: It helped :) but there's one thing.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the id of the progress bar will change base on the id of the tasks that a user enters?
For example I've entered two tasks, I clicked the increment button twice for the first task but none on the second. I refreshed the page but the second one returned to be like the first task.

Comment: That should not be the case.