# Is there a way to add refresh persistence to a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a script for a progress bar that increments progress everytime a button is pressed. 
Html:

```
<head> 
    <script language=JavaScript><script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <progress value="0" max="100" id=p1></progress> 
    <input type=button value='Increse' onClick='incr();'> 
    <div id="numValue">0%</div> 
</body>
```

Is there a way to keep the data of the progress bar when tue page is reloaded?

Comment: use `localStorage` to store data

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734063/how-to-create-and-store-value-of-the-progress-bars-in-local-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a page refresh without closing the window/tab, you could use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

If you want to have the data, even if the window/tab is closed, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But remember to delete the data, after you are done, since `localStorage` doesn't expire.